# How to use joins and averages together in Hive queries

Tags: join, hive, aggregation

I have two tables in hive:

**Table1**: uid,txid,amt,vendor                   **Table2**:   uid,txid

Now I need to join the tables on txid which basically confirms a transaction is finally recorded. There will be some transactions which will be present only in Table1 and not in Table2.

I need to find out number of avg of transaction matches found per user(uid) per vendor. Then I need to find the avg of these averages by adding all the averages and divide them by the number of unique users per vendor.

Let's say I have the data:

**Table1**:

u1,120,44,vend1
u1,199,33,vend1
u1,100,23,vend1
u1,101,24,vend1
u2,200,34,vend1
u2,202,32,vend2

**Table2**:

u1,100
u1,101
u2,200
u2,202

**Example For vendor vend1:**

**u1->** Avg transaction find rate = 2(matches found in both Tables,Table1 and Table2)/4(total occurrence in Table1) =0.5

**u2 ->** Avg transaction find rate = 1/1 = 1

**Avg of avgs** =  0.5+1(sum of avgs)/2(total unique users) = 0.75

**Required output:**

vend1,0.75
vend2,1

I can't seem to find count of both matches and occurrence in just Table1  in one hive query per user per vendor. I have reached to this query and can't find how to change it further.

SELECT A.vendor,A.uid,count(*) as totalmatchesperuser  FROM Table1 A JOIN Table2 B ON A.uid = B.uid AND B.txid =A.txid  group by vendor,A.uid

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are running into trouble with your `JOIN`.  When you `JOIN` by `txid` and `uid`, you are losing the *total* number of `uid`'s per group.  If I were you I would assign a column of `1`'s to `table2` and name the column something like `success` or `transaction` and do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.  Then in your new table you will have a column with the number `1` in it if there was a completed transaction and `NULL` otherwise.  You can then do a `case` statement to convert these `NULL`s to `0`

**Query:**

```
select vendor
    ,(SUM(avg_uid) / COUNT(uid)) as avg_of_avgs
from (
    select vendor
        ,uid
        ,AVG(complete) as avg_uid
    from (
        select uid
            ,txid
            ,amt
            ,vendor
            ,case when success is null then 0
              else success
              end as complete
        from (
            select A.*
                ,B.success
            from table1 as A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 as B
            ON B.txid = A.txid
             ) x
         ) y
    group by vendor, uid
     ) z
group by vendor
```

**Output:**

```
vend1    0.75
vend2    1.0
```

`B.success` in line 17 is the column of `1`'s that I put int `table2` before the `JOIN`.  If you are curious about `case` statements in `Hive` you can find them [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

Comment: I have both the tables partitioned with folder structure(year=2014/month=09/day=05/hour=16/) but when I add the where clause ::   where Table1.year="2014" AND Table1.month="09" AND Table1.day="05" AND Table1.hour= "16" AND Table2.year="2014" AND Table2.month="09" AND Table2.day="05" AND Table2.hour= "16" . I miss some data from Table1. Is there a specific way to apply partitions to tables being JOINED?

Comment: hmmmm.  not sure what u are asking.  You can open another question or we could chat.  Admins get testy about lengthy comment sections that are unrelated to the original question.

Comment: I just meant to ask how I can change the query so that Tables, Table1 and Table2 which are partitioned in hive can be queried the same way but only using the partition specific data. Like I want to run this query hourly on last hour's data, so I want to  JOIN same hour's data from both Tables and from the same partitions. The partitioning structure is /somehdfspath_Table1/year=2014/month=09/day=07/hour=12/datafiles for Table1 & /somehdfspath_Table2/year=2014/month=09/day=07/hour=12/datafiles for Table2. And How do people chat on here?

Answer (score 0):

Amazing and precise answer by GoBrewers14!! Thank you so much. I was looking at it from a wrong perspective.

I made little changes in the query to get things finally done.

I didn't need to add a "success" colummn to table2. I checked B.txid in the above query instead of B.success. B.txid will be null in case a match is not found and be some value if a match is found. That checks the success & failure conditions itself without adding a new column. And then I set NULL as 0 and !NULL as 1 in the part above it. Also I changed some variable names as hive was finding it ambiguous.

The final query looks like :

```
select vendr
    ,(SUM(avg_uid) / COUNT(usrid)) as avg_of_avgs
from (
    select vendr
        ,usrid
        ,AVG(complete) as avg_uid
    from (
        select usrid
            ,txnid
            ,amnt
            ,vendr
            ,case when success is null then 0
              else 1
              end as complete
        from (
            select A.uid as usrid,A.vendor as vendr,A.amt as amnt,A.txid as txnid
                ,B.txid as success
            from Table1 as A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 as B
            ON B.txid = A.txid
             ) x
         ) y
    group by vendr, usrid
     ) z
group by vendr;
```